# Get date from Edittext to DayDecorator

Tags: android, android-edittext, getdate

first of all thanks for reading this :)

Here is my problem.

I got an EditText (User date input) and i want to get a colored background on my CustomCalander for that day using DayDecorator.

```
//EditText I want to get the date
huablauf = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.huablauf);



//adding calendar day decorators

List<DayDecorator> decorators = new ArrayList<>();

decorators.add(new Markierung());

calendarView.setDecorators(decorators);

calendarView.refreshCalendar(currentCalendar);



//class Markierung

private class Markierung implements DayDecorator {

EditText huablauf=(EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.huablauf);

        @Override
        public void decorate(DayView dayView) {

        // I know I have to get my String to a date and then get it to 
        // dayView.getDate()! But my code didn´t work 


        dayView.getDate();
        int color = Color.parseColor("#f9acb8");
        dayView.setBackgroundColor(color);

        }
```

Hope you can understand my problem and anybody can help :)

Thx from Bavaria

Comment: did you used listview for add your calendarview?

Comment: Changed to material calander view

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Override
public void decorate(DayView dayView) {

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy",Locale.getDefault());

    try{ 
        if(dayView.getDate().equals(dateFormat.parse(huablauf.getText().toString()))){
            int color = Color.parseColor("#f9acb8");
            dayView.setBackgroundColor(color);
        }    
    } catch (Exception e){
        //Handle exception.
    }
```

Comment: I was just going going through questions related to DayDecorator. I just realized that this question is old. Too old probably. :/

Comment: Damn it its not too old... :( I took the day as the year xD